# How to remove multiline text from matching strings?

Tags: python, regex, comments

I have the following snippet I would like to completely remove with a regex (or some other method).

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# MODULE PARAMETERS
# These are the variables we have to pass in to use the module specified in the terragrunt configuration above
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there syntax to tell the match to get rid of everything between the two matches?

It seems like it should be easy to do, but for some reason I have only been able to find a regex that pulls *the first and last match* out via this code. I have tried a number of permutations of this regex but can't get it working.

```
...
re.sub(r'# --*[\S\s]*---', '', lines[line])
...
```

This [regex tool](https://regex101.com/r/m93aP8/1) says that my regex should work.

EDIT:

The text I am interested in matching is being read in one line at a time.

```
...
for the_file in files_to_update:
    with open(the_file + "/the_file", "r") as in_file:
        lines = in_file.readlines()
```

And subsequently being iterated over. The snippet above is acutally happening in this loop.

```
for line in range(len(lines)):
```

Comment: What is `lines[line]`? Does it contain all the text that is shown in your question?

Comment: I have updated the syntax in the question but still getting the same result

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed It is basically looping over a file one line at a time. Let me add some more info about that part of it.

Comment: @jmreicha That's what I suspected. If it only contains one line, how do you expect to find a match that goes across multiple lines _in a single line_? Try `re.sub(r'# --*[\S\s]*?---$', '', TheWholeText)`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Ah yep good point :) Probably need to keep track of the match and write something that will remove the lines between the match then?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed so I think I'm on the right track, but now since I am changing the input into a string I am breaking things later because they relying on the text being a list in order to do some other parsing.

Comment: Check my comment under Wiktor's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read in the file into a single variable to be able to run a regex on it, that can match more than one line of text.

You may use

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as fr:
  with open(filesavepath, 'w') as fw:
    fw.write( re.sub(r'^# -+(?:\n# .*)*\n# -+$\n?', '', fr.read(), flags=re.M) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4d2uvV) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nMwkIt/1).

Here, `fr` is the handle of the file you read from, and `fw` is the handle of the file you are writing to. The input for `re.sub` is `fr.read()`, this method grabs the whole file contents and passes to the regex engine.

The regex means:

- `^` - start of a line (due to `re.M`)
- `# -+` - a `#`, space and then one or more hyphens
- `(?:\n# .*)*`  - 0 or more repetitions of a newline, `#`, space, any text up to the end of a line
- `\n` - a newline
- `# -+$` - `#`, space, one or more hyphens and end of a line
- `\n?` - an optional newline.

A non-regex way of removing the comments is by reading line by line, checking if a line starts with `# ---` and set a flag that would enable checking if we are inside the comment or not:

```
for line in fr:
    if line.startswith('# ---'):
        flag = not flag
        continue
    if flag:
        lines.append(line)
        
print("\n".join(lines))
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/wjhfHg).

Comment: This is working to remove the text. I am using some logic later on in the script that is relying on each line being a list for some parsing and I can't think of a good way around that.

Comment: @jmreicha If you're certain that each opening `# ---` line has a closing one, you could write some logic to go through the lines one by one and once you find the "opening line", you remove/ignore it as well as the following lines until you find the "closing line". Alternatively, you can still use the pattern in this answer to get rid of all the unwanted lines at once, and _then_ split the result into multiple lines for further processing.

Comment: This works but I had to add another `lines.append(line)` above the continue statement to get it to capture the first and last comments. Apologies if this wasn't clear in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use string functions with a small function?

```
data = """
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# MODULE PARAMETERS
# These are the variables we have to pass in to use the module specified in the terragrunt configuration above
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

foo
# some other comment
bar

"""

def remover(block):
    remove = False

    for line in block.split("\n"):
        if line.startswith("# ---"):
            remove = not remove
        elif not remove:
            yield line

cleaned = [line for line in remover(data)]
print(cleaned)
```

This yields

```
['', '', 'foo', '# some other comment', 'bar', '', '']
```

Comment: I think this would work but I am concerned about potentially losing other comments.

Comment: @jmreicha: True.

Comment: @jmreicha: Changed it with a small function.